# Moment Timezone and _zones

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie in JavaScript. I just found below code in this page [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Quickstart/Building_simple_functionality]. Although, I know what these `functions` do, but it is not clear to me what `_zones` is ? Could someone explain it in details?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
/* create array of timezones with name & offset */
init: function() {
    var timezones = [];
    for (var i in moment.tz._zones) {
      timezones.push({
        name: moment.tz._zones[i].name,
        offset: moment.tz._zones[i].offset[0]
      });
    }
    this.set('timezones', timezones);
    this._super();
  },
  selectedTimezone: null,
  actions: {
    /* save a timezone record to our offline datastore */
    add: function() {
      var timezone = this.store.createRecord('timezone', {
        name: this.get('selectedTimezone').name,
        offset: this.get('selectedTimezone').offset
      });
      timezone.save();
    },        
    /* delete a timezone record from our offline datastore */
    remove: function(timezone) {
      timezone.destroyRecord();
    }
  }
  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, _zone is an array, property of the moment.tz object which contain all zones, if you have doubts about the zone object I left a link bellow. The underscore is probably due to a common technique to implement private properties in javascript using prefixes.

http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using different versions of `moment` libs.

To find the original versions of libs used in the article see the [`bower.json`](https://github.com/mdn/world-clock/blob/master/bower.json) file in the [tutorial's source code](https://github.com/mdn/world-clock). From this we got the versions used in the tutorial are

```
"moment": "~2.9.0",
"moment-timezone": "~0.3.0"
```

Now lets uninstall the version you have installed and install the version used in the tutorial:

```
bower uninstall moment moment-timezone --save
bower install moment#2.9.0 moment-timezone#2.9.0 --save
```

Restart your server.